# How to divide image into two parts without crossing any object using openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, contour

I am using an object detection machine learning model (only 1 object). It working well in case there are a few objects in image. But, if my image has more than 300 objects, it can't recognize anything. So, I want to divide it into two parts or four parts without crossing any object.

I used [threshold otsu](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) and get this [threshold otsu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtNIH.png). Actually I want to divide my image by this line [expect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYnq.png).  I think my model will work well if make predictions in each part of image.

I tried to use [findContour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYnq.png),  and find contourArea bigger than a half image area, draw it into new image, get remain part and draw into another image. But most of contour area can't reach 1/10 image area. It is not a good solution.

I thought about how to detect a line touch two boundaries (top and bottom), how can I do it?

Any suggestion is appreciate. Thanks so much.

Comment: You can take a look to the [watershed algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) to try to get the boundaries of the objects, then you only need to finde a vertical line which does not touch a point (for example cv::reduce summing each column into one value and then finding the values which are closer to 0 -> in you case you have a border on the top part of the image so it won't be 0)

Comment: My goal is counting object in image. In the first time, I used watershed algorithm, but it will not give me good result if my object is NOT circle shape or rectangle shape (eclipse or a line). In your suggestion, how do I handle if no STRAIGHT LINE meet the needs, such as a curve?

Comment: That is a little bit harder, if you many shapes you may need to try then something else, maybe a classifier can help you. If it is not a straight line it gets more complicated, you may need to find a path of free space. MAybe something simple like start somewhere, and goes down if it is "free" or to the left/right if it is not. Or maybe use distance transform, have a starting point and find the inmediate point (down/left/right) which has the same distance value as the current point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your region of interests are separated already, you can use [connectedComponents](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f) to get the bounding boxes of these regions. My approach is below.

```
img = cv2.imread('circles.png',0)
img = img[20:,20:] # remove the connecting lines on the top and the left sides

_, img = cv2.threshold(img,0,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

labels,stats= cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img,connectivity=8)[1:3]

plt.imshow(labels,'tab10')
plt.show()
```

[image: labels]

As you can see, two regions of interests have different labels. All we need to do is to get the bounding boxes of these regions. But first, we have to get the indices of the regions. For this, we can use the size of the areas, because after the background (blue), they have the largest areas.

```
areas = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA] # the first index is always for the background, we do not need that, so remove the background index

roi_indices = np.flip(np.argsort(areas))[0:2] # this will give you the indices of two largest labels in the image, which are your ROIs 

# Coordinates of bounding boxes
left = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT] 
top = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_TOP] 
width = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH] 
height = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT] 


for i in range(2):
    roi_ind = roi_indices[i]
    roi = labels==roi_ind+1

    roi_top = top[roi_ind]
    roi_bottom = roi_top+height[roi_ind]
    roi_left = left[roi_ind]
    roi_right = roi_left+width[roi_ind]


    roi = roi[roi_top:roi_bottom,roi_left:roi_right]
    plt.imshow(roi,'gray')
    plt.show()
```

[image: roi_0]
[image: roi_1]

For your information, my method is only valid for 2 regions. In order to split into 4 regions, you would need some other approach.